# how to autofill the textfield tag in new.html.erb and save to database using create action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api

I've been able to autofill my text field tags but if i hide them by doing <% instead of <%= they dont save to my database any suggestions?

```
    <%= @low["lowest_price"] %>
      <%= form_tag "/bids", method: :post do %>
      <div>
      <%= label_tag :bid, "place your bid "   %>
      <%= text_field_tag :bid %>
      </div>
      <div>
      <% label_tag :event %>
      <% text_field_tag :event_id, params[:id] %>
      </div>

       <div>
       <% label_tag :user_id %>
       <% text_field_tag :user_id, current_user.id %>
       </div>

       <div>
       <%= label_tag :lowest_price %>
       <%= text_field_tag :lowest_price, @low["lowest_price"] %>
       </div>
       <%= submit_tag "Submit" %>

       <% end %>
```

Heres the create action in the bid controller that this form is connected to

```
     def create
     @bidd = Bid.new(event_id: params[:event_id], user_id:     

      params[:user_id], bid: params[:bid], lowest_price:    

       params[:lowest_price])


 if session[:user_id] == current_user.id
   @bidd.save
   flash[:success] = "bid created."
   redirect_to "/users/#{current_user.id}"
else
   flash[:warning] = 'please sign in'
   redirect_to '/login'
 end
```

heres the page the user show page where the bids will show up on which works as i said when text fields are added manually.

```
    <% @bidds.each do |a| %>
          <p>event: <%= a.event_id %></p>
          <p>Price: <%= a.bid %></p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [hidden field](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/hidden_field_tag).

```
<%= hidden_field_tag :event_id, params[:id] %>
```

However I would not use a hidden field for your current_user.id, that is very bad practice and you have access to that in your session already.

Comment: what would you use as an alternative? sorry i've just begin learning to make rails projects

Comment: If you mean the current_user.id you already have access to that in your controller `session[:user_id]`

Comment: Glad to help. Just a tip, you should really clean up your code a bit. And look into using `form_for @bid` instead of `form_tag`. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html

Comment: will do thanks again I know i def need to clean up my code thank you for the  resource as well